# Update a value from a node in Firebase Realtime-Database in Redux

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Each time a new group is created in my databse, i want to trigger a counter into the /categories/categoryId/groupsCount node in my realtime database with redux. I built this code to get the current count number of the groupsCount value of that particular categoryId and tried to update() with a +1. It didn't work and I don't find any other way to do this simple thing.

```
export const updateCategoryGroupCount = categoryId => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const currentCount = firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/categories/' + categoryId + '/groupsCount')

    await firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/categories/' + categoryId)
      .update({ groupsCount: currentCount + 1 })
      .then(
        dispatch({
          type: UPDATE_CATEGORY_COUNT,
          cid: categoryId,
          total: currentCount + 1;
        })
      );
  };
};
```

How do I get a value from /categories/id/groupCounts using firebase query?

Answer (score 0):

`currentCount` is assigned a promise which is returned from firebase and second query should be called after first one is done.

Change your code like this

```
export const updateCategoryGroupCount = categoryId => {
  return async dispatch => {
       firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/categories/' + categoryId + '/groupsCount')
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot)=> {
         let fetchedObj = snapshot.val(); //the object which is included fields belong to the path of '/categories/' + categoryId + '/groupsCount'
         let currentCount = fetchedObj.currentCount;

         await firebase
         .database()
         .ref('/categories/' + categoryId)
         .update({ groupsCount: currentCount + 1 })
         .then(
            dispatch({
              type: UPDATE_CATEGORY_COUNT,
              cid: categoryId,
              total: currentCount + 1;
            })
         );
      })
    
  };
};
```

Comment: Actually it returned an error: [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: snapshot is not a function. (In 'snapshot()', 'snapshot' is an instance of DataSnapshot)]`

Comment: I solved it by changing the fetchedObj to let fetchedObj = snapshot.val();